# In C++, how can you pass some parameters while leaving others as defaults?

Tags: c++, default-arguments

I'm sure this has been answered here already, but search keeps returning PHP, C# and Java.  I'm specifically asking about C++.

If I have a function that takes five arguments and all of them have default values, but I want to call it explicitly giving a value for the third argument, what do I pass for the first and second arguments? (I know `func(,,"Third")` doesn't work, neither does `func(thirdArg:"Third")`)

Comment: The language doesn't support that, so you need to jump some hoops - see [Boost Parameter Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html) and [Named Parameter Idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/named-parameter-idiom.html).

Comment: named parameter is not supported in c++. You have to wrap it using method overload. :(

Comment: As to the search, limiting it to C++ with `[c++]` should help.

Comment: Did you check the [boost::named_parameters library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html)?

Answer (score 4):

In C++ you have to specify all the parameters up to the defaults, so it would have to be `func("First","Second","Third")`.

C++ also requires that you have defaults at the 'end' of the parameter list, so you can't do something like `func(defaulted, not-defaulted)`

Both of these rules tie into the C++ overload resolution rules.

Comment: Are you 100% sure about that?  I thought there was a keyword or something you could specify which means 'Use the default'... something like func(DEFAULT, DEFAULT, "Third") or similar.

Comment: There's a new ``default`` keyword in C++11, but that's for controlling some default C++ elements like copy/move constructors and assignment operators.

Comment: The default parameters are usually specified by the function designer. Like in win32 with the _USEDEFAULT, like CW_USEDEFAULT or in X11 with a -1 parameter for a size. But these aren't built-in to C++.

Comment: Which is why usually the default value is something like ``0`` or ``nullptr`` so that if a client specifies it, it's easy to remember what the 'default' value is...

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn The keyword `default` isn't new in C++11 (think `switch` statements). The `= default` syntax is.

Comment: @TC - Fair enough. New use of an existing keyword, along with the existing keyword ``delete``. At least they didn't overload the meaning of ``static`` again :)

Comment: It is technically impossible to mix optional and not optional parameters in any order in a function template because no compiler for no language can match the function if a parameter in the middle of the list is optional and you cannot know if its missing or not, or if 2 strings in a row are inserted correctly. You need to overload your function if you want more possibilities to work at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You can make something similar on solution for default-parameters in Java constructors.

But I don't think that it's good practice in C++, especially for functions, because how have said above - position of default-parameters generally accepted after non-default parameters.

Solution achieved by using function overloading:

```
void Foo(int default, int nodefault){
    ...
}

void Foo(int nodefault){
    Foo(10, nodefault); //10 - is default option
}

int main(){
    Foo(3); //calls Foo(10, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is non trivial. May be you can try boost parameter. You can pass parameter as such then,

`func(third_="third")`

Please check =>

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html#named-function-parameters

Comment: You could work around it using the [Named Parameter Idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter) which is what Boost implements here, but that's still not feature of the C++ language.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn My answer was more for referring possibility of doing the required.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support in the language. However an idiom often used by C++ programmers to replace the lack of *bash-like positional parameters* is the [Named Parameter idiom.](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/named-parameter-idiom.html).

Assuming that your function is a member method of a class, you can easily apply this idiom :

Basically, you have methods (possibly accessors) to modify the state of your object. Each method returns a non-const reference to `this`, allowing method chaining.

**Example:**

```
class Person{

public:

    Person& setAge(int agep) { age = agep ; return *this; }

    Person& setWeight(double weightp) { weight = weightp ; return *this; }

    Person& setName(const std::string& namep) { name = namep ; return *this; }

private:
    int age = 0;
    double weight = 0.0;
    std::string name;
};

int main(){
    Person p;

    p.setAge(42).setName("Kurt"); // set age and name, but not weight
}
```